# Show how much there is of a certain value in each column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas data frame contains several columns, some of them have missing values which show up as a `?` sign. I want to run a for loop to print how much `?` there is in each columns of the data. I'm doing something like this:

```
colnames = ['col_1','col_2','col_3']

for i in colnames:
    print(f'In the {i} feature, the value - ? - occurs {data.i.value_counts()["?"]} times')
```

The error I get is :

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'i'
```

So I think that problem is with this part - `data.i.value_counts()`, I tried `data[i].value_counts()` but that didn't work eaither..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For count values avoid `value_counts`, because failed selecting `?` if value not exist in column. Simplier is compare values by `?` and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
for i in colnames:
    print(f'In the {i} feature, the value - ? - occurs {data[i].eq("?").sum()} times')
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the dataframe is `data`, if OP wants to use `.value_counts()`, adjust to the following

```
colnames = ['col1','col2','col3']

for i in colnames:
    print(f'In the {i} feature, the value - ? - occurs {data[i].value_counts()["?"]} times')
```

Or, if one want to know for all columns of the dataframe `data`, use

```
for i in data.columns:
    print(f'In the {i} feature, the value - ? - occurs {data[i].value_counts()["?"]} times')
```

If, on another hand one wants to prevent the KeyError (see first note), one can use `.isin` with `.sum()` as follows

```
for i in colnames:
    print(f'In the {i} feature, the value - ? - occurs {data[i].isin(["?"]).sum()} times')
```

---

**Notes:**

- If a specific column doesn't have `?`, one will get a `KeyError: '?'`, so it might be more convenient to select the columns that have `?`, instead of applying to all the dataframe columns.